# How do I rename a host in Cloudera Manager / CDH4?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

I just added a datanode into the cluster via Cloudera Manager and realized it's misspelled. Instead of foo.bar.net, I put foo.bar.et... How do I rename my host?!?

Answer (score 0):

Delete it and re-add with the right host name.  If the host wasn't correct in the first place, the Cloudera agent was probably never installed on the node and you'll need to run the entire process anyway.

Comment: That's weird, is it a valid host name and does it have a heartbeat?